# Check wallet address balance programmatically in PHP using Blockchain wallet api

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I'm tyring to fetch my wallet balance programmatically using the [Blockchain wallet api](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api). Currently I was expecting that a simple `api` call to [https:/blockchain.info/merchant/$my_guid/balance?password=$my_blockchain_password](http://https:/blockchain.info/merchant/$my_guid/balance?password=$my_blockchain_password) would have returned the value but it currently returns [this page](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api).

Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> **The Blockchain Wallet API provides a simple interface Merchants can use to programmatically interact with their wallet.
>   Installation**
>
> To use this API, you will need to run small local service which be responsible for managing your Blockchain Wallet. Your application interacts with this service locally via HTTP API calls. [Click here for complete setup instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3).

So you need to install the service, then replace the `blockchain.info` in that link with the IP to your server, or if it's on the same machine `localhost:3000`